# asp.net textbox mode DateTimeLocal format

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am trying to convert the format of a `DateTimeLocal` Textbox from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

If I use the format `mm/dd/yyyy` converting the textbox to datetime and using the `ToShortDate()` function confuses between the days and months. how do I change the format of the textbox? I want it the way that when I select a date, it will also show to the client in `dd/mm/yyyy` and will send it to the server in the same format.
If it is possible as well to display and choose just the date without the hour.

The textbox code

[image: Text Box code]

the 2 textbox with default `mm/dd/yyyy` format

[image: DateTimeLocal text box with default mm/dd/yyyy]

Comment: Hi it would be easier to answer you if you embed the image in your question body, and instead of making a screenshot of the code - use a code block to paste the relevant code inside.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your webforms question is

> ASP.NET Webforms client side:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="placeholderTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
```

> ASP.NET Webforms server side:

[image]

---

> ASP.NET MVC:

```
MyDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm");
```

---

> **Update** to your comment below: The question is not clear on what you are trying, but if you want to do it on client side

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">                                 
 <ItemTemplate>                                     
  <asp:TextBox ID="myDateTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'>
  </asp:TextBox>                                
 </ItemTemplate>                             
</asp:TemplateField>
```

---

Additionally, I would recommend something like a jQuery date picker like so to pretty up the formatting

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#myFormattedDatepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"});
  });
  </script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="myFormattedDatepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Hey, I want to change the DateTimeLocal textbox so it will automatically show the dd/mm/yyyy format to the client and the server. when I converted it to DateTime format as you did, the mm became the day while the dd became the months because the DateTimeLocal format is mm/dd/yyyy. currently I am converting it oppositely so converting to mm/dd/yyyy gives me what I want (dd/mm/yyyy). that is why I asked I want to change the textbox format itself, not to convert

Comment: i am not following you, but you can change the string format as you want to dd/mm

Comment: How do I do that? all I want is to change the DateTimeLocal to dd/mm. Isn't it possible?

Comment: can you add some comments on what is the issue with the format, and is it client side or short format